# Shell script to check one script output and then run second script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want a script to run a main.ksh to run both one.ksh and second.ksh only if output of one.ksh matches "1". So if the output is anything other than "1" then second.ksh shouyld not run.

```
 cat one.ksh
 #!/usr/bin/ksh
 echo "1"

cat second.ksh
#!/usr/bin/ksh

echo "2"
```

I did this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

ksh .ksh > one.txt

file="one.txt"

while read line
do

if [ $line -eq 2 ] ;then
ksh second.ksh
else
echo "one.ksh is no good"
fi
done <"$file"
```

Any better way ro this is good?

Comment: And ... you don't know how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `echo 1` to proceed from the first script, you should use `exit 0`. If it shouldn't proceed, `exit 1`.

This is the standard way of signaling success and failure in Unix.

Once you do this, you can use any of:

```
first.ksh && second.ksh
```

or

```
if first.ksh
then
    second.ksh
fi
```

or

```
set -e  # Automatically exit script if a command fails
first.ksh
second.ksh
```

Answer (score 1):

```
out=`one.ksh`

if [ "x$out" == "x1" ]; then
    second.ksh
fi
```

Comment: You can simplify a bit: `[[ "$(one.ksh)" == "1" ]] && second.ksh`